# What is Java's interface equivalent of Thread.sleep()?

Tags: java, eclipse, multithreading, interface, thread-sleep

I'm programming a robot that uses an interface with buttons and a text box and stuff, and I know that if you are using

```
Thread.sleep();
```

then it will pretty much break your interface. I know that

```
Thread.sleep();
```

pretty much just pauses your current thread and resumes it after an allotted amount of time. I need to have a slight pause in my program without breaking my interface, such as an interface equivalent of

```
Thread.sleep(1000);
```

I've looked for hours and I can't find anything to create a slight pause in one part of your program while maintaining an interface. Also I don't know about multithreading so please explain stuff in as much detail as possible. Thanks in advance for helping me!

Comment: What does your code currently do when it has nothing to do? How do you, for example, wait for the user to tell you to do something? Conceptually, the way to think about this is as follows: You don't have anything to do now. But you will have something to do in a second or if the user tells you to do something. So arrange the program to be notified in a second. And then do whatever it is you do when there's nothing to do, waiting for either user input or the notification to happen. Treat timer notifications the same as user input.

Comment: I didn't understand what you mean in "break your interface"

Comment: @edubriguenti I believe he means, for example, that if the user presses a button, he won't notice because his code is sleeping.

Comment: I don't know what you are trying to do, but I think you can use FutureTask, like in this example: http://www.journaldev.com/1650/java-futuretask-example-program

Answer (score 2):

Everything in a Java Swing user interface runs on a single, special thread (the Swing thread or "event dispatching thread"). If you block this thread with a `Thread.sleep()` then your user interface stops responding.

To be able to sleep (i.e. deliberately delay some processing) without blocking the user interface, your program may need to run on multiple threads. I suggest you take a look at the [Java tutorial on this topic](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/). Multithreading is a fairly advanced topic that can't really be summarised in a short answer.

It's not clear what you are trying to achieve with your `sleep` - if you just want some action to be triggered at a future time, then the [Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) class may do what you need without needing extra threads.

There are also some [helper classes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html) in the Java libraries for running tasks on other threads in a GUI application.

Comment: Thanks I looked into multithreading and basic multithreading should solve my problem. I can use the main class as my GUI and call other classes as separate Threads to keep them running and have them pause while the GUI is running constantly.